# A calculation from Berline-Getzler-Vergne

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold. Suppose that $D$ is a Dirac-type operator on a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded Clifford module $E\rightarrow M$, in the sense that $D^2$ is a generalised Laplacian. Define the the action of $T^*M$ on $E$ by the formula
$$c(df):=[D,f],$$
where $f$ is a smooth function on $M$. It is claimed (Berline-Getzler-Vergne "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators" page 113) that:

$$c(d(fh))=[D,fh]=fc(dh)+hc(df),$$
$$c(df)^2=\frac{1}{2}[[D,f],[D,f]]=\frac{1}{2}[[D^2,f],f]=-|df|^2.$$

I would like to know how to get these two identities. It also seems to me that
$$[[D,f],[D,f]]$$
should be $0$?

Thanks for your help.